# Is there a way to prevent my for loop doubling duplicate letters when comparing two strings for identical letters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops, compare

I've got an array of strings and a string. Using a for loop, iterating through both the array and the string, I'm hoping to return the letters that are the same in both.

My solution works until there is a duplicate letter in the array. When there is a duplicate, the
relevant letter gets doubled, for example 'aaa' would return 'aaaaaa'.

Below is the code that I have tried most recently.

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Apple"];

let myString = "apple";

const fruit = fruits[2].toLowerCase();

for (let i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < myString.length; j++) {
    if (myString[j].indexOf(fruit[i]) !== -1) {
      console.log(myString[j]);
      return myString(j)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `myString[j].indexOf(fruit[i])` is calling `indexOf` on a string made by a single character. While I think you meant to check if `fruit[i]` belonged to the whole `myString` value. Or maybe not .. but in that case why didn't you just compare the character at that position for both strings? and why having two counters?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make a function or change the return statement so we have a [mcve]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the goal of the code. Are you trying to find the letters that are common to `myString` and all words in `fruits`? Could you add an expected output for `myString = "apple"`?

Comment: there are 6 A's in const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Apple"];
... try console.log the fruit, I think you will see what is happening. .. Not sure what you wanna do, but you can break out of an inner for loop afaik. Maybe that''s what you wanna do on a hit.

Comment: @Medda86 There are actually 7 A's in `fruits`, no? 3 in "banana" and 1 in each of the remaining 4 words.

Comment: what exactly is your code supposed to output/return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the occurrences of each letter of `myString` in each element of the array, use:

```
fruit.toLowerCase().split('')
    .filter(letter => myString.includes(letter))
    .join('')
```

where `fruit` is an element of the array. Here is a demo:

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Apple"];

let myString = "apple";

for (const fruit of fruits) {
    console.log(
        myString,"<>",
        fruit,"...>",
        fruit.toLowerCase().split('')
        .filter(letter => myString.includes(letter))
        .join('')
    );
}
```

However, to determine which letters of `myString` appear in each element of the array use:

```
myString.split('')
    .filter(letter => fruit.toLowerCase().includes(letter))
    .join('')
```

Here is a demo:

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Apple"];

let myString = "apple";

for (const Fruit of fruits) {
    const fruit = Fruit.toLowerCase();
    console.log(
        myString,"<>",
        fruit,"...>",
        myString.split('')
        .filter(letter => fruit.includes(letter))
        .join('')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to look at each word in the array

You may want to fiddle with the toLowerCases depending on your needs

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Apple"];
let myString = "apple";

const findCommonLetters = (array, string) => {
  const uniqueStringLetters = new Set(string.toLowerCase()); // unique letters in string

  const matches = array.map(fruit => [...new Set(fruit.toLowerCase())]
    .filter(letter => uniqueStringLetters.has(letter)) // find matching letters
    .join(''));
  return matches;
};

console.log(findCommonLetters(fruits, myString));
```

Comment: Guesswork is rarely productive. Just ask the OP for clarifications.

Comment: True, but my years answering JS questions give me a pretty good chance at guessing right. And if not, then it is likely trivial to tweak the code to give what OP wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if the whole string matches the fruit,
then print the letters from that. I got lost in your inner for loops.
Check this one out:
https://jsfiddle.net/peu54ry2/

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Apple"];
const myString = "apple";

for (let i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
  if (fruits[i].toLowerCase() == myString) {
    console.log(fruits[i]);
  }
}
```